# Using AlertDialog inside Button.onClick messes up value of getView(int position) in ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-studio, android-arrayadapter, android-alertdialog

I've been trying to figure this out for about 2 weeks but no luck at all. I'm trying to add a confirmation message in my `onClickListener` by using `AlertDialog`, and the `setPositiveButton` of AlertDialog will be the one to do the things that I want to happen, but it messes up the `int position` value in `getView` . Instead of getting the position of the item I clicked on, it gets the position of the last item. I tried doing `Toast` message inside the `onClick`(**NOT** inside the `AlertDialog`) and it returns the proper position, but when I try to `Toast` message inside the `AlertDialog` it changes the position value. I stuck and don't how to make this work.

Here is my Adapter.Class

```
public class myOrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<myOrder> {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    AlertDialog ad;

    public class ViewHolder{
        TextView tableNum;
        TextView itemName;
        TextView itemQuantity;
        TextView custName;
        Button btnStatus;
    }

    public myOrderAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<myOrder> orderList) {
        super(context, 0,orderList);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final myOrder orderList = getItem(position);

        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        if(convertView == null){

            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout,parent,false);

            viewHolder.tableNum = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tableNum);
            viewHolder.itemName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
            viewHolder.custName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.custName);
            viewHolder.itemQuantity = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemQuantity);
            viewHolder.btnStatus = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.statusButton);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        }

        else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.tableNum.setText("Order for Table: "+orderList.getTable_id());
        viewHolder.itemName.setText(orderList.getItem_name());
        viewHolder.custName.setText("Customer Name: " + orderList.getCust_name());
        viewHolder.itemQuantity.setText("QTY: " + orderList.getQuantity());


        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Order.context);
        builder.setTitle("Confirmation");
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_confirm);
        builder.setMessage("Is this Ready to Serve?");


        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),orderList.getOrder_id()+ "+" + orderList.getItem_name() + "+" + position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });


        ad = builder.create();

        viewHolder.btnStatus.setText("Ready");
        viewHolder.btnStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),orderList.getOrder_id()+ "+" + orderList.getItem_name() + "+" + position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ad.show();
            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }


}
```

**NOTE :**
I set the `Toast` message the same way as `Button.onClickListener` in the `builder.setPositiveButton` to check if the value changes, and yes it does change. Need some help and guidance, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are creating the AlertDialog for every view created even to the last view(for the last item) which is the reason why you are getting the position to be the last index of your item list. Try something like below, this will only create the dialog when you click on the button from one of the view.

```
public class myOrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<myOrder> {

public class ViewHolder{
    TextView tableNum;
    TextView itemName;
    TextView itemQuantity;
    TextView custName;
    Button btnStatus;
}

public myOrderAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<myOrder> orderList) {
    super(context, 0,orderList);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final myOrder orderList = getItem(position);

    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

    if(convertView == null){

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout,parent,false);

        viewHolder.tableNum = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tableNum);
        viewHolder.itemName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
        viewHolder.custName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.custName);
        viewHolder.itemQuantity = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemQuantity);
        viewHolder.btnStatus = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.statusButton);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }

    else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.tableNum.setText("Order for Table: "+orderList.getTable_id());
    viewHolder.itemName.setText(orderList.getItem_name());
    viewHolder.custName.setText("Customer Name: " + orderList.getCust_name());
    viewHolder.itemQuantity.setText("QTY: " + orderList.getQuantity());


    viewHolder.btnStatus.setText("Ready");
    viewHolder.btnStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),orderList.getOrder_id()+ "+" + orderList.getItem_name() + "+" + position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            createDialog(position);
        }
    });


    return convertView;
}

private void createDialog(final int position) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setTitle("Confirmation " + position);
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.pencil);
    builder.setMessage("Is this Ready to Serve? " + position);


    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override 
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),orderList.getOrder_id()+ "+" + orderList.getItem_name() + "+" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 
    }); 

    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override 
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        } 
    }); 

     builder.create().show();
}
}
```